# Elastic Search don't return highlight results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm sending a request like this:

```
{
    "from": 0, 
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "_all": "presidencia"
        }
    }
    ,
    "aggs": {
        //... some aggregations 
    }
    ,
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "nomeOrgaoSuperior": {}
        }
    }
}
```

But my response doesn't come with *highlight* field.
Response:

```
{
    "took": 68,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {"total": 15, "successful": 15, "failed": 0},
    "hits": {
        "total": 692785,
        "max_score": 0.48536316,
        "hits": [
            //Some hits...
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        //some aggs ...
    }
}
```

Do i need some extra configuration on my index or what?

Comment: Can you try to add `"require_field_match": false` to your `highlight` section?

Comment: note, that "highlight" fields should be inside every hit inside "hits" array - where your "//Some hits..." is. Are they there?

Comment: @AndrzejMartyna No... They aren't there =/

Comment: @Val I tried to add that but still nothing happens =/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem. I was trying to use highlight on field that wasn't analysed by my analyser. So, my search was analysed and the fields i was trying to get the highlight wasn't. That made the highlighter to never return a match.